# Checking computercraft Lua code to operate a door

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I am making a vault with some custom mods and I am using a computercraft computer to control the door but I can only open the door and not close. Is this code right?

```
term.setTextColor(colors.yellow)
print("Vault-Tec Door Computer")
term.setTextColor(colors.white)
print("What Command Would You Like To Do?")
term.setTextColor(colors.blue)
print("Vault.Open")
print("Vault.Close")
print("")
term.setTextColor(colors.white)
io.write("Vault-Tec:")
io.close()
    if io.read()=="Vault.Open" then
        term.setTextColor(colors.red)
        print("VAULT DOOR OPENING, PLEASE STAND BACK")
        term.setTextColor(colors.white)
        redstone.setAnalogOutput("bottom", 0)
        sleep(5)
    end
    if io.read()=="Vault.Close" then
        term.setTextColor(colors.red)
        print("SHUTTING VAULT DOOR, PLEASE STAND BACK")
        term.setTextColor(colors.white)
        redstone.setAnalogOutput("bottom", 15)
        sleep(5)
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first if statement calls `io.read()` and reads whatever is typed and compares it to `Vault.Open`.  Your next if statements reads *the next thing* that was typed and compares it to `Vault.Close`.  You should only read what was input once and store it in a variable, then you can use that value in multiple places.

```
.....
local valutStatus = io.read()
if valutStatus == "Vault.Open" then
    term.setTextColor(colors.red)
    print("VAULT DOOR OPENING, PLEASE STAND BACK")
    term.setTextColor(colors.white)
    redstone.setAnalogOutput("bottom", 0)
    sleep(5)
end
if valutStatus == "Vault.Close" then
    term.setTextColor(colors.red)
    print("SHUTTING VAULT DOOR, PLEASE STAND BACK")
    term.setTextColor(colors.white)
    redstone.setAnalogOutput("bottom", 15)
    sleep(5)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Lua so I did not know how to fix it but I see what you did and you helped me :D!

Comment: Note that code-only answers are sometimes deleted here. Would you please add to this, by way of an edit, an explanation of what the problem was and why this solves it?